# Will WM_SETCURSOR be sent to parent if you handle it and don't call DefWindowProc() in it?

Tags: c, winapi

The docs say that `DefWindowProc()` sends `WM_SETCURSOR` to parent. If you don't call `DefWindowProc()` from `WM_SETCURSOR` but instead just return FALSE will `WM_SETCURSOR` be sent to parent of your window? In other words will the code that sent you `WM_SETCURSOR` send `WM_SETCURSOR` to the parent of your window if you just return FALSE? This is not a dialog window.

```
//Are these two the same?
    case WM_SETCURSOR:
        //More code
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

    case WM_SETCURSOR:
        //More code
        return FALSE;
```

Comment: Hard to guess.  It is going to depend on whether this is a parent window itself and a child window called DefWindowProc().  It isn't really sane code, not with it commented out anyway, WM_SETCURSOR ought to do only one thing.  You'll have to try, always use the 1st version if you don't want to.

Comment: @HansPassant: Part of dynamically setting the cursor involves evaluating state. If you don't need to set your cursor dynamically, there's little reason to handle the `WM_SETCURSOR` message at all; the class cursor will do just fine. If you are handling `WM_SETCURSOR`, chances are, that you do need to do more than just setting the cursor.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061121-15/?p=28943

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: that depends. If you are called directly by Windows and return FALSE, nothing more will happen, but that may not be the situation.

If you are called by the `DefWindowProc` or some other window procedure then to return FALSE is to say you have not handled the message. Further processing is quite possible, but exactly what would depend on the caller.

It probably isn't a good idea. Either return TRUE or call the `DefWindowProc`, like the manual says.